# Overwrite Model tostring method

Tags: php, laravel-4

I was wondering if it was possible to overwrite the `tostring()` method of a Model in Laravel 4.

I would like to be able to write `echo $model;` in a view and it prints that object in a specific way instead of having to create a new function in this model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. Just overwritting the magic function `__tostring()`

```
public function __toString() {
    return "Object toString";
}
```